# Write a function that gets the average of the numbers in L2 that are larger than the largest number in L1

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme

Write a function `average-above-max`, which takes 2 lists, `L1` and `L2`. `L1` and `L2` are both simple lists, which do not contain nested lists. Both lists may have non-numeric elements.

The result of the function is the average of the numbers in `L2` that are larger than the largest number in L1.

If there is no number in `L1`, all the numbers in `L2` should be used to calculate the average.

If there is no number in `L2`, the average is `0`.

For example, the result of `(average-above-median (list 2 'a 1) (list 'b 5 3 1))` should be `4`.

And this is what I have:

```
 (define (filter l n)
   (cond
     ((null? l) empty)
     ((number? (car l)) (cons (car l) (filter (cdr l))))
     (else (filter (cdr l)))))
```

which only picks numbers out of a list.

Comment: An order. In Scheme. CS101 homework?

Comment: @Moron - I'd be surprised to find CS101 courses teaching Scheme. But yes, looks like homework.

Comment: I rejected the edit to add the [homework] tag, because I believe we're not doing meta tags any more.

Comment: @TheBigO: I personally know of one University which started its programming classes in Scheme :-)

Comment: Oughtn't that to be `average-above-max`, not `average-above-median`?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't seen CS101, but I hope I solved your problem:

```
(define (avg xs)
  (/ (foldl + 0 xs) (length xs)))

(define (list-max xs)
  (let loop ((xs xs)
             (e (car xs)))
    (if (empty? (cdr xs))
        e
        (loop (cdr xs) (max e (car xs))))))

(define (average-above-median xs ys)
  (let* ((xsnum (filter number? xs))
         (ysnum (filter number? ys)))
    (if (empty? ysnum)
        0
        (if (empty? xsnum)
            (avg ysnum)
            (avg (filter (lambda(x) (> x (list-max xsnum))) ysnum))))))
```

Example:

```
> (average-above-median (list 2 'a 1) (list 'b 5 3 1))
4
> (average-above-median (list) (list 'b 5 3 1))
3
> (average-above-median (list 2 'a 1) (list))
0
> (average-above-median (list) (list))
0
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I would also factor out a call to `list-max`, because it probably makes your Big O even bigger :-D